# Delete a row from array by component event in that array using React

Tags: reactjs

Below is a basic example of the problem I'm experiencing.

I have a list of items that are in an array. The user can add another item to the list, and it shows on the page. Each item has a delete button and that **delete button is a component inside the array item** (this is so each item could have a button that does a different action.. in my example the action is deleting, but later it might be "Send" or "Delete" or "Cancel" or "Edit"...)

The trouble is, when I click the "Action" in this case delete, I want to know which item in the array this was. This way, I can get the array index and delete it. Or later grab additional details from the

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

function App() {

  const [list, setList] = useState([])

  function addRow(){
    let newRow = {
      name: "Test",
      action: <span onClick={e=>removeThisRow()}>REMOVE</span>
    }

    setList([
      ...list,
      newRow
    ])
  }

  function removeThisRow(){
    // need this to remove the specific item from my list array...
    console.log("removing...")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        list.map(item=>(
          <div>
            {item.name} | {item.action}
          </div>
        ))
      }

      <div onClick={e=>addRow()}>ADD ROW</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working and tested

```
function App() {

  const [list, setList] = React.useState([])

  function addRow(){
    let newRow = {
        id: Math.random(),
      name: `Test-${Math.random()}`,
      action: (id) => <span onClick={()=>removeThisRow(id)}>REMOVE</span>
    }

    setList([
      ...list,
      newRow
    ])
  }

  function removeThisRow(id){
    setList(l => l.filter(li => li.id !== id))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        list.map((item)=>(
          <div key={item.id}>
            {item.name} | {item.action(item.id)}
          </div>
        ))
      }

      <div onClick={e=>addRow()}>ADD ROW</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Id is just random number, I would use something more unique like `uuid()`

Comment: great suggestion, in fact it was what I had tried originally... BUT, you end up with the same problem and that is inside your removeThisRow function, the list doesn't know about the item by index yet. If you console your 'list' there you will see its always one item behind.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Function doesn't know about index when it's defined, but it takes it as a parameter on click so the index is correct. The log of the list will be one behind if you log it right after setList because that's async.

Comment: Updated my example with an id, it's working here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6qdf7pc2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach to dynamically adding/editing/removing items from an array. Instead of unnecessarily creating JSX within an array, you can map over the array list and edit/remove the row based upon a unique `id`.

You can get even more sophisticated by adding two additional input toggles **before** adding a new row. These two toggles might add an `isEditable` and `isRemovable` properties to the row when when it's created. These properties can then be used to dynamically include or exclude buttons when the list is displayed. This is a cleaner approach as you're not recreating the same buttons over and over for each row, but flexible enough to conditionally render them.

On a related note, using the array index as a [`key` is anti-pattern](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

**Demo Source Code**:

[image: Edit Dynamically Add/Edit/Remove Row]

**Demo**: https://q3wph.csb.app/

**Code**:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import Button from "./components/Button";
import Input from "./components/Input";
import Switch from "./components/Switch";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
  const [editRow, setEditRow] = React.useState({
    id: "",
    value: ""
  });
  const [newRowValue, setNewRowValue] = React.useState("");
  const [newRowIsEditable, setNewRowEditable] = React.useState(true);
  const [newRowIsRemovable, setNewRowRemovable] = React.useState(true);

  const removeItem = (removeId) => {
    setList((prevState) => prevState.filter(({ id }) => id !== removeId));
  };

  const editItem = (editId) => {
    const { name } = list.find((item) => item.id === editId);
    setEditRow({ id: editId, value: name });
  };

  const updateRowItem = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setEditRow((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, value }));
  };

  const handleRowUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { id, value } = editRow;

    if (!value) {
      alert("Please fill out the row input before updating the row!");
      return;
    }

    setList((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, name: value } : item
      )
    );
    setEditRow({ id: "", value: "" });
  };

  const addNewRowItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!newRowValue) {
      alert("Please fill out the new row item before submitting the form!");
      return;
    }

    setList((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        id: uuid(),
        name: newRowValue,
        isEditable: newRowIsEditable,
        isRemovable: newRowIsRemovable
      }
    ]);
    setNewRowValue("");
    setNewRowEditable(true);
    setNewRowRemovable(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Dynamically Add/Edit/Remove Row</h1>
      {list.length > 0 ? (
        list.map(({ id, name, isEditable, isRemovable }) => (
          <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body" key={id}>
            {editRow.id === id ? (
              <form onSubmit={handleRowUpdate}>
                <Input
                  placeholder="Add a new row..."
                  value={editRow.value}
                  handleChange={updateRowItem}
                />
                <Button color="secondary" type="submit">
                  Update Row
                </Button>
              </form>
            ) : (
              <>
                <h2 className="uk-card-title">{name}</h2>
                {isEditable && (
                  <Button
                    className="uk-margin-small-bottom"
                    color="primary"
                    type="button"
                    handleClick={() => editItem(id)}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </Button>
                )}
                {isRemovable && (
                  <Button
                    color="danger"
                    type="button"
                    handleClick={() => removeItem(id)}
                  >
                    Remove
                  </Button>
                )}
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div>(Empty List)</div>
      )}
      <form
        className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body"
        onSubmit={addNewRowItem}
      >
        <Input
          placeholder="Add a new row..."
          value={newRowValue}
          handleChange={(e) => setNewRowValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Switch
          label="Editable"
          handleChange={(e) => setNewRowEditable(Boolean(e.target.checked))}
          name="Editable"
          value={newRowIsEditable}
        />
        <Switch
          label="Removable"
          handleChange={(e) => setNewRowRemovable(Boolean(e.target.checked))}
          name="Removable"
          value={newRowIsRemovable}
        />
        <Button
          className="uk-margin-small-bottom"
          color="secondary"
          type="submit"
        >
          Add Row
        </Button>
        <Button color="danger" type="button" handleClick={() => setList([])}>
          Reset List
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm attaching an attribute to the span, named `index` and accessing that in removeThisRow.

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  function addRow() {
    let newRow = {
      name: "Test",
      action: (
        <span index={list.length} onClick={(e) => removeThisRow(e)}>
          REMOVE
        </span>
      )
    };

    setList([...list, newRow]);
  }

  function removeThisRow(e) {
    // need this to remove the specific item from my list array...
    const index = e.target.getAttribute("index"); // got the index as a string
    // Do whatever you want
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <div>
          {item.name} | {item.action}
        </div>
      ))}

      <div onClick={(e) => addRow()}>ADD ROW</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Won't work. you are setting non-existent index. list.length is last index + 1

Comment: Plz analyze it carefully. It works flawlessly. Here's a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-haze-t7j42?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have analyzed it carefully now and it doesn't work, a couple of problems there; You are setting index to DOM, that's not a good practice especially when you can easily get `index` from `map` function. Also what happens if I add row (gets index 0) add another one (index 1) and another one (index 2); remove index 1. I end up with rows 0 and 2 (length 2) add row (index 2), now I have two entries with the same index and if I remove one, both will go.